# Remote Profiling in Jprofiler

Tags: java, jvm, jprofiler, code-profiling

I have my sample java application running on port 9010 in one of my Azure VM with an IP let say xxx.xx.xx.254. I have installed Jprofiler in another Azure VM, with IP xxx.xx.xx.159.  How can i profile the application from xxx.xx.xx.159 (Both machines are Windows)?

I have tried remote profile using direct connection, but it couldn't connect. Also checked with SSH, that too failed as 'Connection timeout'

Is there any step by step process for this connection?

Solution to the problem, how to connect and profile the Remote application from my local machine using JProfiler

Answer (score 0):

**"Direct connection"** means that you can connect to remote machine on the selected profiling port (8849 by default). This is usually not the case unless the remote machine is on a private network because firewalls will prevent the connection. Also, in that case you must have added the `-agentpath` VM parameter for loading the JProfiler agent to the start command of the profiled JVM. This parameter can be obtained by invoking the "Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration" wizard.

With **SSH connections** in JProfiler, you can tunnel the connection through SSH. This will work if you have an SSH server running on the remove machine. SSH connections work for VMs where the JProfiler agent has been loaded with the -agentpath VM parameter as well as in attach mode for all JVMs that are running on the remote system.

The related documentation is available at

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/main/profiling.html